# python django can't get any views to work

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to get django set up so I can start learning it. But I can't even display even a simple view. Here's my file structure:

```
âââ __init__.py
âââ __init__.pyc
âââ manage.py
âââ media
âââ pages
âÂ Â  âââ views.py
âââ settings.py
âââ settings.pyc
âââ templates
âÂ Â  âââ base.html
âÂ Â  âââ home.html
âââ urls.py
âââ urls.pyc
```

Sorry about the weird sybols, that's how the linux computer printed it out with the tree command. Here's my url file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'testsite.pages.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^testsite/', include('testsite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

Basically, I want example.com to point to the pages.views.home view. But it can't find it and keeps giving me the error: `Could not import testsite.pages.views. Error was: No module named pages.views`

I'm new to both python and django so I'm probably doing something stupidly simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `__init__.py` to your `pages` directory, to make it a "package" in python parlance.

This is a bit of non-obvious behaviour from python. Now you know.

Comment: @LordZardeck You really wouldn't. I had to ask about this too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not import testsite.pages.views. Error was: No module named pages.views
```

You need to make `pages` importable. Put an `__init__.py` in the `pages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create blank file `__init__.py` in `pages`directory.